# Laravel 8: Undefined variable when loading a Blade into another Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

**THE SITUATION:**
I'm making a side Menu that is populated by getting data from a table (MySQL).
Every `<li>` represents one item for the menu:

```
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 2</li>
<li>item 3</li>
```

etc...

**THE PROBLEM:**
All works fine when I see its blade, but when I include it in the main blade, it throws the variable `$all_items` that contains the data to make the `<li>` is not recognized `(Error: "variable not found error")`

**THE CODE:**

**web.php**

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('items', 'MenuCmpItemsController@show');
```

**MenuCmpItemsController.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\MenuCmpItems;
use DB;

class MenuCmpItemsController extends Controller
{
    public function show(){
        $all_items = DB::table('tbClassrooms')->select("room_number")->get();
        return view('items', ['all_items'=>$all_items]);
    }
}
```

**items.blade.php** (works fine when visiting the URL '/items')

```
@foreach ($all_items as $item)
<li>{{ $item->cmp_name }}</li>
@endforeach
```

Now I want to include items.blade.php in auth.blade.php which is the one that contains the following side menu structure:

```
<div class="collapse show" id="sidemenu">
  <ul class="nav">         
      @include('items')
  </ul>
</div>
```

But it throws

> $all_items is undefined

WHAT I TRIED:

1. I checked if it could be something else, for example, I replaced "$all_items" with a text, and it loads the text in auth.blade.php, so it seems like the problem is the variable `$all_items`
2. I checked if

```
return view('items')->compact('all_items');
```

would make any difference but no.

Any suggestions or ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: How do you load `auth.blade.php`?

Comment: When you call `auth.blade.php`, is your Controller method called? Don't think so. Might want to take a look at [View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#view-composers)

Comment: You have to pass `@include('items', ['all_items'=>$all_items])` to the include

Answer (score 1):

What is your folder structure? in the resources folder

Answer (score 1):

Solution suggested by shaedrich should resolve your issue.

```
@include('items', ['all_items'=>$all_items])
```